# Why this code produce the footnote in the first page?

Tags: footnotes, article, affiliation, paper, email

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\title{Title}


\date{}

\begin{document}


\author[1]{Caio}
\author[2]{Tizio}
\affil[1]{blabla}
\affil[2]{blablabla}



\setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}

\footnote[2]{ Corresponding author \\ \textit{E-mail addresses}: \texttt{tizio@gmail.com} (tizio),   Support from:}

 
%\renewcommand\Affilfont{\itshape\small}


\maketitle
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}




\section{Introduction}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you don't want to add a footnote with marker, but only an additional footnote text. So use `\footnotetext` instead of `\footnote`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\title{Title}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\author[1]{Caio}
\author[2]{Tizio}
\affil[1]{blabla}
\affil[2]{blablabla}

\footnotetext[2]{Corresponding author \\ \textit{E-mail addresses}: \texttt{tizio@gmail.com} (tizio),   Support from:}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `\footnote` should be after `\maketitle`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with up-to-date LaTeX
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

\title{Title}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\author[1]{Caio}
\author[2]{Tizio}
\affil[1]{blabla}
\affil[2]{blablabla}

\maketitle
\footnote[2]{Corresponding author \\ \textit{E-mail addresses}:
  \texttt{tizio@gmail.com} (tizio),   Support from:}

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```